# How do I open Skype's contact list when a chat window is open

Tags: skype, window-management

When a user has a Skype chat window open but closes the main Skype window (the contact list), then clicking the Skype icon in Unity only restores the chat window, but not the main Skype window (the contact list).

How can one restore the main window without closing the chat window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Ubuntu 14.04 with the default unity dock, the Skype application is a big blue icon in the list.  Right clicking it gives me a popup menu with three main windows listed, one named after the current chat, one for File Transfers, and one for " - Skype".  Click that last one seems to activate the main contacts window.

If it is then offscreen, you may need to press alt+space to open the window's system menu, then hit 'm' to select Move, then wave the mouse around or to the edge of the screen (to activate 'glue to screen edge' behaviour) to force the window to reposition itself onscreen.  I switch between multiple monitors when I move between two work locations and my windows frequently get stuck offscreen.

Answer (score 3):

Click on the Skype indicator icon, and click "Activate".

[image: Sceenshot of Skype indicator menu]

Comment: Thank you, however there is no Skype indicator icon.

Comment: @dotancohen: Are you using normal Ubuntu with Unity and Skype 4.1.0.20 or later? In that case, it's a bug. [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: Not me, but rather a colleague. It seems to be stock Ubuntu 12.10 with whatever version of Unity came with it. What is worse, we see two "dots" indicating two Skype windows open, but the main window cannot be got to without closing the chat window.